# How to concat two fields and use the result in WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, window-functions

I have to get all oldest records based on the date-time information.

**Data**

```
Id |  External Id | Date                | Time
1  |  1000        | 2020-08-18 00:00:00 | 02:30:22
2  |  1000        | 2020-08-12 00:00:00 | 12:45:51
3  |  1556        | 2020-08-17 00:00:00 | 10:09:01
4  |  1919        | 2020-08-14 00:00:00 | 18:19:18
5  |  1919        | 2020-08-14 00:00:00 | 11:45:21
6  |  1919        | 2020-08-14 00:00:00 | 15:54:15
```

**Expected result**

```
Id |  External Id | Date                | Time
2  |  1000        | 2020-08-12 00:00:00 | 12:45:51
3  |  1556        | 2020-08-17 00:00:00 | 10:09:01
5  |  1919        | 2020-08-14 00:00:00 | 11:45:21
```

I'm currently doing this

```
SELECT *
FROM RUN AS T1
WHERE CONCAT(T1.DATE, T1.TIME) = (
     SELECT MIN(CONCAT(T2.DATE, T2.TIME))
     FROM RUN AS T2
     WHERE T2.EXTERNAL_ID = T1.EXTERNAL_ID
)
```

Is it a correct way to do ?

Thank you, regards

**Update 1 : Data type**

`DATE` column is `datetime`

`TIME` column is `varchar`

Comment: Why do you store date and time separately? Can one of the two be null or what else is the reason? What data types are the two columns? Can you please show us the `CREATE TABLE` statement?

Comment: It is not my database so I don't know ... I updated the post with detail of both column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a window function such as `DENSE_RANK()`

```
SELECT ID, External_ID, Date, Time
  FROM 
  (
   SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY External_ID ORDER BY Date, Time) AS dr,
          r.*
     FROM run r 
   ) AS q
 WHERE dr = 1
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=29dc9df77f300ec75e76db38fdfe4fb3)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However I'm facing this issue : Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'. Maybe due to the version of the database ? : `Microsoft SQL Server 2012` ?

Comment: Oracle doesn't need aliasing for the subquery but SQL server does, just alias it @Royce . I've just edited due to this.

Comment: Thank you for the demo. I just have a question please. Then I can use `q` to do some `inner join` right ? Like `...) AS q INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON q.External_Id = ...` ? Moreover, `PARTITION BY` will order by DESC the date and time and `dr = 1` will take only the first record (so the oldest one). Correct ? Just to be sure to understant correclty the request.

Comment: Yes, of course aliasing and consecutive joinings are possible, `PARTITION BY` stands for `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`(default `ascending`, so `dr` starts from `1`) picks the oldest one for each External_ID values whenever equal to `1` @Royce

Comment: Thank you for the explanation however i'm not sure to understand the "equal to 1". `DENSE_RANK()` returns a number?

Comment: you're welcome @Royce , check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) out.